# App does not start in emulator

Tags: android

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.android.lewis.cspeedometer, PID: 2337
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.lewis.cspeedometer/com.android.lewis.cspeedometer.CSpeedometer}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.lewis.cspeedometer/com.android.lewis.cspeedometer.PhoneCallReceiver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.lewis.cspeedometer/com.android.lewis.cspeedometer.PhoneCallReceiver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
                      at com.android.lewis.cspeedometer.CSpeedometer.updateSpeed(CSpeedometer.java:114)
                      at com.android.lewis.cspeedometer.CSpeedometer.onCreate(CSpeedometer.java:51)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8619', transport: 'socket'

Comment: Please add a valid question here:http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, the error stacktrace tells you exactly what to do: The activity is not added to the manifest.

Comment: `voted to close` Before you post question at-least take some effort to read the error.....

Answer (score 0):

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Declare your activity in Android 
Mainfest like this

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"></activity>
```